# Display bug with Front Camera, Video and VideoDisplay in Adobe AIR (Flex 4.6.0) for Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.6

I'm current working wits `AS3` and `Flex 4.6` to create an android application.
i'm using the front camera and attach it to a local `Video` object that i add as an child to an `VideoDisplay` object.

When i debug on my computer everything is working perfectly, but when i build the project and run it on my Android device my local video display becomes an gray grid.
As example i took an picture of the device.[image: Picture of the problem]

I wrote this method based on a post here on Stackoverflow to initialize the front and back camera.

```
private function InitCamera():void {
            var CamCount:int = ( Camera.isSupported ) ? Camera.names.length : 0;
            for( var i:int = 0; i < CamCount; i++ ) {
                var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera( String( i ) );
                if( cam ) {
                    if( cam.position == CameraPosition.FRONT ) {
                        CamFront = cam;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if( cam.position == CameraPosition.BACK ) {
                        CamBack = cam;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if( cam.position == CameraPosition.UNKNOWN ) {
                        CamFront = cam;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And i wrote this method to create an `Video` object, attach the front `Camera` as the default camera and add the `Video` as an child to an `VideoDisplay`:

```
private function SetUpLocalVideo():void {
            Debug( "Setting up local video" );
            LocalVideo = new Video( this.LVideo.width, this.LVideo.height );
            LocalVideo.attachCamera( CamFront );

            LVideo.addChild( LocalVideo ); <--- this is the VideoDisplay
        }
```

I've been searching on the internet for an solution, but so far i failed to find any.

Do any one else had this problem before ? can you share you solutions with me ?
I appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you include full camera permissions into your app descriptor?

Comment: Yes in the Main-App XMl is uncommented this line "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>"

Comment: Ok, I tried it on my phone and I could see this bug , but then it stopped to appear. It also seems that this grid is a result of three simultaneous video outputs. I also saw something like that on old crt displays when I tried to set all possible modes with asm. I So, I guess that it may be caused by some conflict with other camera-using apps(like smart rotation), or by improper camera deinitialization during debug sessions interruptions, or by trying to receive input from two cameras at the same time. Do you use real camera resolutions of your device?

Comment: This bug can also be avoided and fixed with this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547082/raw-camera-display-on-air

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the **render mode** to **direct** on your application.xml

```
<renderMode>direct</renderMode>
```

If it still doesn't work, change the **dpi settings to 240** of your main flex application.