# Raw Camera Display on Air

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, camera

We are trying to display Camera on a part of screen(raw camera). It shows a strange black and white display on Android device, but it works properly on emulator. What do you have any idea about how to solve this problem ?

EDIT:  "Tour de Mobile Flex" application in Camera->Raw Camera have same problem. [image]

Comment: If I were you, I'd try it on other devices as well, because this might also be device's fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set `<renderMode>direct</renderMode>` in app.xml.  That configuration solve my problem.

Comment: confirmed, this works for me to. I've been looking for a while for a solution to this problem. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting render mode to direct works for me as well (AIR 3.4 on Nexus S 4.1.2).

If you don't want to manually manage your manifest file, this can be done in the publishing settings dialog ("Edit Application Settings") in CS6.